# Generic messaging

Tags: c++, generics, types, messaging, erasure

I am working on a messaging system on C++. I have;

```
class MessageData
{
public:
    typedef std::vector<std::shared_ptr<MessageData>> MessageList;

    virtual int getValue(std::shared_ptr<int>) { throw "Not implemented!"; };
    virtual float getValue(std::shared_ptr<float>) { throw "Not implemented!"; };
    virtual std::string getValue(std::shared_ptr<std::string>) { throw "Not implemented!"; };
    ...
    ...

    virtual ~MessageData() {};
};

template <typename T>
class Message : public MessageData
{
    T val;
public:
    static std::shared_ptr<Message<T>> Make(T val) { return std::make_shared<Message<T>>(val); };
    static T Get(std::shared_ptr<MessageData> in) { return in->getValue(std::make_shared<T>()); };
    Message(T i) { val = i; };
    T getValue(std::shared_ptr<T> out) override { return *out = val; }
    ~Message() {};
};
```

Using these, I can send/receive generic messages of different length conveniently using e.g;

```
sendMessage(MessageData::MessageList{
                Message<std::string>::Make("paint"),
                Message<int>::Make(14),
                Message<float>::Make(129.3f),
                ...
            });
```

Then I get the values;

```
sendMessage(MessageData::MessageList data) {
    auto a = Message<std::string>::Get(data[0]);
    auto b = Message<int>::Get(data[1]);
    auto c = Message<float>::Get(data[2]);
    ...
}
```

The downside is that I have to list all the types I need to use in MessageData class. This isn't a big deal as I can limit the types I want to support but I'm really curious about how to templatize the type list without using a 3rd party library. Or is there a completely different and better method that I can use with similar clean syntax and type safety to pass messages around?

Comment: boost::any is helpful here

Comment: I dont want to use a third party library

Comment: look at the code of boost::any and reimplement it (this may take a while). or wait until c++17 then you have std::any

Comment: Isn't there any small addition to my code that will do the trick? :) I feel like there should be one.

Comment: Here is a nice post about type erasure. Maybe you can take something from it: http://www.artima.com/cppsource/type_erasure.html

Comment: You can have a base class which wraps this (you loose type safety though or have to use dynamic_casts later)

Comment: @Hayt: It shouldn't take more than five or ten lines to implement a rudimentary `any`...

Comment: In any case have a look at: https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2013/11/18/type-erasure-part-i/. also: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Inheritance-Is-The-Base-Class-of-Evil. If you have a virtual base class I wouldn't call it type erasure rather than interfacing. type erasure is the case when you don't have a common base class but try to detect if your type has a certain behaviour.

Comment: OK, I have changed the title to get rid of any misunderstandings.

Comment: Why not use some kind of serialization scheme instead? Even if you don't want to use a third-party library (why not?)  you could at least take a look at e.g. [Boost serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/serialization/) to see how it's done.

Comment: boost is not "a third party library", it's what half the standard library is copied from. `boost::variant` or `boost::any` is the right answer.

Comment: @richard Do you think current solution is bad and should not be used?

Comment: @AliNaciErdem having written a few message bus implementations (with differing behaviour requirements) I can say this: The more you re-use well-tested code such as the standard library or boost, the less time you will spend debugging what you have written. 
If the types of data passed through the message are known, then this argues strongly for a variant. If they are unknown at compile time, then clearly an `any`. `any` is a lot more problematic for the user to deal with, because he is forced to deal with type mismatches at runtime. Prefer variant if you can.

Comment: @joachim Is boost serialization type-safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've developed a decent solution to my problem.

```
class MessageData {
public:
    typedef std::vector<std::shared_ptr<MessageData>> MessageList;
    virtual ~MessageData() {};
};

template<typename T>
class Message : public MessageData {
    T val;
public:
    template<typename U>
    friend U GetMessage(std::shared_ptr<MessageData> in);

    Message(T i) { val = i; };
};

template<typename T>
T GetMessage(std::shared_ptr<MessageData> in) {
    std::shared_ptr<Message<T>> tmp = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Message<T>>(in);
    if (tmp) {
        return tmp->val;
    } 
    throw "Incorrect type!";
};

template<typename T>
std::shared_ptr<Message<T>> MakeMessage(T val)
{
    return std::make_shared<Message<T>>(val);
};
```

Then send & receive values using;

```
sendMessage(MessageData::MessageList{
                MakeMessage(std::string("paint")),
                MakeMessage(14),
                MakeMessage(129.3f),
                ...
            });

sendMessage(MessageData::MessageList data) {
    auto a = GetMessage<std::string>(data[0]);
    auto b = GetMessage<int>(data[1]);
    auto c = GetMessage<float>(data[2]);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I shamelessly accepted my answer :) Using a 140Mb boost pack just for 30 lines of code? Thanks but no!

Comment: This only provides runtime type safety. If you want compile time checks do not use this :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to make your code more generic is:

```
template <typename ... Ts>
class MessageDataImp;

template <typename T>
class MessageDataImp<T>
{
public:
    virtual ~MessageDataImp() = default;
    virtual T getValue(std::shared_ptr<T>) { throw "Not implemented!"; };
};

template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
class MessageDataImp<T, Ts...> : public MessageDataImp<T>, public MessageDataImp<Ts...>
{
public:
    using MessageDataImp<T>::getValue;
    using MessageDataImp<Ts...>::getValue;
};

template <typename ... Ts>
class MessageDataTs : public MessageDataImp<Ts...>
{
public:
    typedef std::vector<std::shared_ptr<MessageDataTs<Ts...>>> MessageList;
};

using MessageData = MessageDataTs<int, float, std::string>;
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that it's a simple multiple-reader, multiple-writer message bus based on a non-prioritised queue, I think I'd start with something like this:-

Note that I have used boost::variant/optional. These could easily be replaced with std:: versions if you have those available.

I have used variant because it efficiently caters for most use cases with compile-time safety.

The std/boost::any version would require significant (and possibly unwelcome) care for users of your bus.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

template<class Mutex> auto get_lock(Mutex& m) { return std::unique_lock<Mutex>(m); }

template<class...Types>
struct message_bus
{
    using message_type = boost::variant<Types...>;

    void push(message_type msg) {
        auto lock = get_lock(mutex_);
        messages_.push(std::move(msg));
        lock.unlock();
        activity_.notify_one();
    }

    boost::optional<message_type> wait_pop()
    {
        boost::optional<message_type> result;
        auto lock = get_lock(mutex_);
        activity_.wait(lock, [this] { return this->stopped_ or not this->messages_.empty(); });
        if (not messages_.empty())
        {
            result = std::move(messages_.front());
            messages_.pop();
        }
        return result;
    }

    void signal_stop()
    {
        auto lock = get_lock(mutex_);
        stopped_ = true;
        lock.unlock();
        activity_.notify_all();
    }


    std::queue<message_type> messages_;
    std::mutex mutex_;
    std::condition_variable activity_;
    bool stopped_ = false;
};

static std::mutex emit_mutex;

template<class T>
void emit(const T& t)
{
    auto lock = get_lock(emit_mutex);
    std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << ": " << t << std::endl;;
}

int main()
{

    using bus_type = message_bus<std::string, int>;
    bus_type mb;

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i)
    {
        threads.emplace_back([&]
        {
            for(;;)
            {
                auto message = mb.wait_pop();
                if (not message)
                    break;
                boost::apply_visitor([](auto&& data) { emit(data); }, message.value());
            }
        });
    }

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; ++i)
    {
        mb.push("string: " + std::to_string(i));
        mb.push(i);
    }
    mb.signal_stop();

    for (auto& t : threads) if (t.joinable()) t.join();

}
```

Comment: Once I have boost::variant, my question is irrelevant.

Comment: @AliNaciErdem precisely. Why reinvent a well-maintained wheel?